# My compound listener won't work

Tags: java, android

I've added a compound listener so I can add the integers in order to receive a score and set a xml text to it.

The score is still only giving 0. I don't know if it's because the integers are arrays(There was an error and I used alt enter to fix it, this changed to ints to arrays that are final.)

In summary, the point of this code: check if the checkbox's are ticked, when a button is pressed, and then assign 0 or 1 to it. Add them and then assign an output text to it.

```
package xyz.ashraf.whoisdelasalle;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

/**
 * Created by Ashraf on 3/2/2016.
 */
public class check_Button extends Pop_sallian{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.popwindow_sallian);
        // Connects The variable to an xml id


        TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

        final int[] con = {0};
        final int[] fai = {0};
        final int[] res = {0};
        final int[] edu = {0};
        final int[] com = {0};
        //sets the variable to 0


         OnCheckedChangeListener checkedListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                switch(buttonView.getId()){
                    case R.id.concern:
                        con[0]++;
                        break;
                    case R.id.faith:
                        fai[0]++;
                        break;
                    case R.id.respect:
                        res[0]++;
                        break;
                    case R.id.education:
                        edu[0]++;
                        break;
                    case R.id.community:
                        com[0]++;
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        int score = con[0] + fai[0] + res[0] + edu[0] + com[0];
        // adds the variables together to form a score

        if(score == 0){
            output.setText("score of 0");
        } else if(score == 1){
            output.setText("score of 1");
        } else if(score == 2){
            output.setText("score of 2");
        } else if(score == 3){
            output.setText("score of 3");
        } else if(score == 4){
            output.setText("score of 4");
        } else if(score == 5){
            output.setText("score of 5");
        } else{
            output.setText("Unknown");
        }
        // changes the output text based on score value
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You create a listener but where do you assign it to the checkboxes?

Comment: yes for example R.id.concern

Comment: could you please explain, I don't understand what's wrong.